# Are these applications of universal specification correct?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In fact, I have two questions about universal specification, because I'm not sure about its application, so the next applications are okey:
$$\forall x \forall y [R(x, z) \rightarrow \exists y R(f(w, y), y)] \vdash \forall z [R(f(w, y), z) \rightarrow \exists y R (f(w, y), y)]  $$
and

$$\forall x \exists y R (x, y)\vdash  \exists x R(x, x) $$
I think that the second one is incorrect, but I don't have any counterexample.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The second one is incorrect, because the "Universal Specification" axioms says: "$∀x α → α[t/x]$, where $t$ is *substitutable for* $x$ *in* $α$" and $x$ is **not** substitutable for $y$ in $∃yR(x,y)$.

Comment: Also the first one is wrong; in the premise $∀x∀y[R(x,z) → \ldots]$ we have that $z$ in $R(x,z)$ is free, while in the conclusion $∀z[R(f(w,y),z) → \ldots]$ it is bound.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: You are welcome :-)